# How long does it take you to create a container from a 4GB docker image?

Tags: docker

I just need some kind of reference on how long it should take to create a container based on a 4GB docker image. On my computer it is currently taking >60 seconds, which causes `docker-compose` to timeout. Is this normal for a modern workstation with SSD disks and a decent CPU? Why does it take so long?

The docker context is ~6MB, so that should not be the issue here, but I know it could be had the context been larger.

It's running on a linux host, so it's also not the IO-overhead tax you pay when running docker in a VM like Docker for MAC does.

I just don't understand why it's so slow, if it's expected for these large images, or if I should try some other technology instead of Docker (like a virtual machine, ansible scripts or whatever).

Comment: `docker create <image>` is what is taking a long time. So the container is not  really doing anything, it's the docker process of creating a container from the image that is taking long.

Comment: It's not normal behavior. Can you tell us about this container--share the Dockerfile, perhaps?

Comment: I'd normally expect creating a container to be pretty quick, independent of the image's size.  Do you have a volume (maybe an anonymous volume from a Dockerfile `VOLUME`) that's copying significant content out of the image?  (My past experience has been that ~1 GB is the practical upper limit for an image size, but I haven't run into this particular problem.)